# How to set 'int' datatype for a column with n/a values

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgres with column 'col' with age values. This column also contains n/a values.
When I am applying a condition of age < 15, I am getting below error:

```
[Code: 0, SQL State: 22P02]  ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "n/a"
```

I am using below query to handle the n/a values but I am still getting the same error:

```
ALTER TABLE tb 
    ADD COLUMN col CHARACTER VARYING;

UPDATE tb

Set col = 
        CASE
                WHEN age::int <= 15
                THEN 'true'
                ELSE 'false'
        END 
;'
```

Please see 'age' is in text format in my table. I have two questions here:

1. How can I set the datatype while creating the initial table (in the create table statement)?
2. How can I handle n/a values in above case statement?

Thanks

Comment: You shouldn't store numbers in `text` columns to begin with. And why isn't `col` a `boolean` if you only want to store true/false in there? Storing columns named "age" is more often then not a bad design as well, as that will change with every day. It's usually better to calculate something like that on the fly. The same goes for the new column. It would be much better if you put all that into a VIEW rather than permanently updating those two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **really** fix your data model and store numbers in `integer` columns.

You can get around you current problem, by converting your invalid "numbers" to null:

```
UPDATE tb
  Set col = CASE 
              WHEN nullif(age, 'n/a')::int <= 15 THEN 'true'
              ELSE 'false'
            END;
```

And it seems `col` should be a `boolean` rather than a `text` column as well.